# disable toggling capslock when CTRL+CAPS LOCK is pressed, but leave functionality as is if CAPS LOCK is pressed without CTRL

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to configure hotkeys in IntellliJ to use a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> as a first stroke shortcut (second is CTRL+W but that's irrelevant), but when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> the usual capslock function is toggled along with a led on a keyboard. This makes it tedious to use this combination as a primary stroke, because I have to disable capslock each time afterwards.

I want to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> combination to be handled specially and disable toggling capslock mode ONLY when that combination is pressed (i.e. otherwise normal functionality with a sole <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> being pressed should work as normal).

Can I do that?

Comment: you could try https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper